# What is this anime about people who can transform themselves into giant robots with the help of a device/talisman?

Tags: moldiver

I only saw the last part of this Anime. A few minutes. So, I cannot give many details.
I think it was a movie and I think it was around the 2nd half of the 1990s. Because it was on a weekend program where they showed Anime movies and once "*X (1999)*" was one of them.

What I remember from that short scene:

- The Anime is about people, who can transform themselves into giant robots with the help of a device/talisman (?). However, the transformation rips their clothes apart and when hey change back, they are totally naked.
- The protagonist is a girl. She has straight, shoulder-lenght, brown(ish) hair and she wears it in pigtails maybe. Anyway, her hair is tied up somehow. Either she cannot transform till the end of the movie or she has problems with fighting... but in the end she transforms and fights well.
- There is and older guy (not old!), who may be her "teacher", who teaches her how to transform(?) He has brown hair and glasses I guess. In that end scene he came to help the girl out but she did well on her own, so he just watches and changes back. Being experienced, he brought spare clothes with him, but there is a giant dog (I think it is his) that takes them. So the guy ends up chasing the dog naked. They were under a bridge that time.
- The art was great and detailed.

This is **ALL** I remember.

Comment: Could it be this one? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/Moldiver?from=Main.Moldiver

Comment: It is Moldiver. Thank you. Though I remember it in a newer style and a bit different.

Comment: @nhahtdh, you should probably make your comment into a full answer, so user6307 can accept it and you'll get the reputation benefits. =)

Answer (score 6):

The series that OP was looking for is [**Moldiver**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldiver), a 6-episode 1993 OVA anime series.

[image: Volume 4 Cover]

The female protagonist is **Mirai**, the brown-haired girl in the middle. And the glasses guy on the lower right corner is **Hiroshi**, her brother and inventor of the *Mol Unit* - the transformation device.

Plot summary by [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=699):

> Hiroshi Ozora invents the Mol Unit, a device that makes its user invincible. His plans of becoming a super hero are short lived however when his sister, Mirai, accidently modifies the suit configuration. Now she is forced to save Tokyo by herself from the evil Machinegal and his gang of all-female androids.

Below is the screenshot 18 minutes into episode 2 showing Mirai getting her clothes ripped off when transforming with her clothes still on.

[image: 18:30 Episode 2]

Below is a series of screenshot of Hiroshi getting naked inside the tunnel of the stadium to prepare for the transformation but failed (17 minutes into episode 2), after which he contacted Mirai and asked her to transform (above). When he was instructing Mirai (21 minutes into episode 2), **a dog came and took his clothes away behind him**.

[image: Hiroshi]

There wasn't any scene of him chasing the dog, though.

---

When I first tried to identify the anime in question, I checked through the list of anime and manga in [Clothing Damage](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClothingDamage) trope, and [Moldiver](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/Moldiver)'s screenshot kind of matches the description for the female protagonist.

[image: tvtropes.org]

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [Android Kikaider: The Animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Kikaider_%28anime%29) <sup>[[ANN]](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=964)</sup>

[image]

> Dr. Kohmyoji creates Jiro (Kikaider) but an explosion occurs. When Dr Kohmyoji's kids, Mitsuko and Masaru, their father was nowhere to be found, Jiro wandering aimlessly in a remote area eventually meets Mitsuko. Mitsuko teaches Jiro to go into his robot form and about the GEMINI system inside him. The two grow closer together but the relationship development halts when a mysterious flute playing causes Jiro to attack Mitsuko, which causes her to believing he is a mad machine. Jiro inevitably leaves Mitsuko and Masaru in fear of being destroyed. Mitsuko then hires Hanpei Hattori and his apprentice Etsuko Sarutobi to find Jiro and bring him home. Throughout the story, Jiro encounters robots and learns more about Professor Gill and the evil organization DARK. A reoccurring android named Hakaider causes Jiro out of control by whistling (similar to Gill's flute). The more Mitsuko encounters Jiro the more she falls in love with him. When Mitsuko and Jiro reunite, they search for Mistuko's mother who is revealed to be in love with Professor Gill but could not bare the pain of being away from her children and gives them the location to Professor Gill's headquarters right before she killed herself. After they discover the location, Jiro attempts to fight Hakaider alone and also discovers the brain inside Hakaider's head is that of Dr. Kohmyoji's. Dr. Kohmyoji overtakes Hakaider's body before Hakaider could destroy it and infiltrates the headquarters. Once Professor Gill discovers Dr. Kohmyoji is in control he sends his robots to attack them. Jiro was able to give the brain to Hanpei in order to put it back into Dr. Kohmyoji's body. Professor Gill attempts to control Jiro with his flute, but Jiro to is able to overcome it. Hakaider then attempts to kill Professor Gill for betraying him and destroys the place along with Gill. Hanpei, Mitsuko and Etsuko able to escape, but didn't see Jiro escape with them. In the end, Mitsuko has hope that Jiro will return to them

As explained form [Android Kikaider wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Kikaider_(anime)), they are able to go into their robot forms because of the GEMINI system inside of them.

Comment: Can you provide any more information? Specifically about how this show matches the description in the question?

Comment: sure i will edit my answer